# 500 Error on apache server - "AllowOverride not allowed here"

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have set up a server on my Mac (OSX 10.9) but it's returning a 500 error with the following message in the error log…

```
[alert] [client ::1] /Users/user/Sites/mysite/.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here
```

Here's the code in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride All

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteMap lc int:toLower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^i/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)$ /items/?id=$1&range=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ /category/?menu=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And here's the relevant httpd.conf code (let me know if there's anything else that would help)

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Sites/mysite"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/user/Sites/mysite">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Take the `AllowOverride` directive out of your `.htaccess` file. It's only permitted in a `<directory>` section

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AllowOverride All` doesn't belong in the htaccess file. It's used in the server config (httpd.conf) to set what an server config parameters an htaccess file *can override*. So obviously, it would be wrong to be able to configure what parameters htaccess files can override from within htaccess files.

Remove it from your htaccess file. You've already defined `AllowOverride All` in your httpd.conf in the right places.

Comment: Awesome! thanks. I'm now getting the same message about the RewriteMap line. Where shall I move that to?

Comment: @Tom RewriteMaps can't be defined in htaccess files either (but you can *use* them in an htacces file). You need to define those in the httpd.conf, but **outside of the `<Directory>` containers**.

Answer (score 2):

`AllowOverride` controls `.htaccess` security and behaviour and cannot be set inside of `.htaccess` itself.

Remove `AllowOverride All` from the `.htaccess` file, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Take `AllowOverride All` out of your **.htaccess** file.